# Name a Table with a Variable in LUA (LÖVE Engine)?

Tags: dynamic, lua, naming, lua-table

Basically:

- I am making a game in the LÖVE Engine where you click to create blocks
- Every time you click, a block gets created at your Mouse X and Mouse Y
- But, I can only get one block to appear, because I have to name that block (or table) 'object1'

Is there any way to create table after table with increasing values? (like object1{}, object2{}, object3{}, etc... But within the main table, 'created_objects')

But only when clicked, which I suppose rules out the looping part (but if it doesn't please tell me)

Here's my code so far, but it doesn't compile.

```
function object_create(x, y, id) **--Agruments telling the function where the box should spawn and what the ID of the box is (variable 'obj_count' which increases every time a box is spawned)**

currobj = "obj" .. id **--Gives my currently created object a name**

crob.[currobj] = {} **--Is supposed to create a table for the current object, which holds all of its properties. **

crob.[currobj].body = love.physics.newBody(world, x, y, "dynamic")
crob.[currobj].shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(30, 30) 
crob.[currobj].fixture = love.physics.newFixture(crob.[currobj].body, crob.[currobj].shape, 1)     **--The properties**
crob.[currobj].fixture:setRestitution(0.3)
```

But what should I replace [currobj] with?

---

#### Solved

Found what I was looking for. Here's the code if people are wondering:

function block_create(x, y, id) --(the mouse x and y, and the variable that increases)

```
blocks[id] = {}
blocks[id][1] = love.physics.newBody(world, x, y, "dynamic")
blocks[id][2] = love.physics.newRectangleShape(45, 45)
blocks[id][3] = love.physics.newFixture(blocks[id][1], blocks[id][2])
blocks[id][3]:setRestitution(0.2)
blocks[id][4] = math.random(0, 255) --The Color
blocks[id][5] = math.random(0, 255)
blocks[id][6] = math.random(0, 255)

blockcount = blockcount + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

i would probably do something like this.

```
local blocks = {} -- equivalent of your crob table

function create_block(x, y)
    local block = funcToCreateBlock() -- whatever code to create the block
    table.insert(blocks, block)
    return block
end
```

if you wanted to get a reference to the block you just created with the function, just capture it.

```
-- gives you the new block, automatically adds it to the list of created blocks
local new_block = create_block(0, 10)
```

that sticks block objects in your block table and automatically gives each one a numeric index in the table. so if you called create_block() 3 times for 3 different mouse clicks, the `blocks` table would look like this:

```
blocks = {
    [1] = blockobj1,
    [2] = blockobj2,
    [3] = blockobj3
}
```

you could get the second block obj from the blocks table by doing

```
local block2 = blocks[2]
```

or you could loop over all the blocks in the table using `pairs` or `ipairs`

```
for idx, block in pairs(blocks) do
     -- do something with each block
end
```

sorry if this doesn't exactly answer your question. but from what you wrote, there didn't seem to be a real reason why you'd need to name the blocks anything specific in the crob table.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it did give me clues to edit my code, but I still need to know, is there a way of naming tables dynamically? Like dynamic variables, but as the categories in a table. (I need to replace the [currobj] in my code with something that increases every time the function gets run. Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to create a variable, say named 'block1', and then create a key in the crob with that same name?

Comment: yes, and then get that to increase (block2, block3, block4...) and create a new table with that name every time the function is run

Comment: then you can do what 'Back in a Flash' stated in his answer to create variables in the global namespace. i don't really see why anyone would want to do that, but you can do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want those tables to be global, then you can do something like:

```
sNameOfTable = "NAME"
_G[sNameOfTable] = {1,2}
```

and then you will have a table variable `NAME` as depicted [here](http://codepad.org/GMNDeM3S) (Codepad).

Otherwise, if you want it to be a child to some other table, something like this would also do:

```
tTbl = {}
for i = 1, 20 do
  local sName = string.format( "NAME%02d", i )
  tTbl[sName] = {1,2}
end
for i, v in pairs(tTbl) do
  print( i, v )
end
```

Don't worry about the unsorted [output here](http://codepad.org/YL4QzKN1)(Codepad). Lua tables with indexes need not be sorted to be used.